# Nested For Each with msgbox

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, nested-loops

Goal: Search each cell of each sheet in the workbook to see if there is an error. If there is an error, a msgbox pops and gives you the ability to change the cell from the error to either "Yes" or "No".

Problem: 
Instead of looping through the sheets it loops back through the cells on the same sheet a second time.
I tried moving the final End If after Next Sht but it came up with a compile Error "Next Without For".

I also know from other reading it is not good to use a Cell reference in the Next Cell, and realize this may be the issue, but I am not sure how to correct it.

```
Sub test()
On Error Resume Next
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngError As Range
Dim Sht As Worksheet

Set Sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = Sht.Range("A1:N2000")
Set rngError = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)

For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    If Not rngError Is Nothing Then
        For Each Cell In rngError
            Answer = MsgBox("message in the box", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Name Change Check")
                If Answer = vbYes Then
                      Range(Cell.Address) = "Yes"
                Else
                      Range(Cell.Address) = "No"
                End If
        Next Cell
    End If

Next Sht

End Sub
```

As a side note, the below part of the code works perfectly on its own. Its only when I added the nested loop that it went haywire.

```
If Not rngError Is Nothing Then
    For Each Cell In rngError
        Answer = MsgBox("message in the box", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Name Change Check")
            If Answer = vbYes Then
                  Range(Cell.Address) = "Yes"
            Else
                  Range(Cell.Address) = "No"
            End If
    Next Cell
```

Comment: What do you mean with loops back through cells on the same sheet a second time? That part is not very clear. It loops all sheets. However you haven't fully declared: `Range(Cell.Address) = "Yes"` which references the `ActiveSheet`. Is that what you meant? Then change to `.Range(Cell.Address) = "Yes"`

Comment: Also, you set your range outside your loop. You want to refer to all these sheets their own rng and rngError i suppose. Since you loop through each sheet you don't have to set sht outside your loop.

Comment: `Set rng` *inside* your loop

Comment: @JvdV. this resulted in a Complie Error "invalid or unqualified Reference"

To expand on what I meant in my explanation, the msg box goes through and lets me change the cell to yes/no for all the cells with errors, but then it starts going back through those same cells i just changed as if there were still an error there and asks me to select yes/no again.

Comment: @Cybernetic.nomad, I put the range inside the loop and it started with the errors (like it should) and then started going through each cell in the sheet asking me to change it to yes/no.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Sub test()
On Error Resume Next
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngError As Range
Dim Sht As Worksheet

Set Sht = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set rng = Sht.Range("A1:N2000")

GoTo lable

lable:
Set rngError = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)

For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    If (Not rngError Is Nothing) Then
      If rngError <> "Yes" And rngError <> "No" Then
        For Each Cell In rngError
            Answer = MsgBox("message in the box", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Name Change Check")
                If Answer = vbYes Then
                      Range(Cell.Address) = "Yes"
                Else
                      Range(Cell.Address) = "No"
                End If
                rngError = Nothing
        GoTo lable
        Next Cell
          End If
    End If

Next Sht

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Nakul, thanks for trying! This code works on a single sheet but doesn't loop through the sheets.